# JPA In expression: what is collection size limit?

Tags: java, jpa, collections

I'd like to run a JPA query (eclipselink) like:

```
select t from SomeEntity t where t.branch.id in :branchList
```

and pass a collection as branchList.

The question is what is the collection size limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JPA does not set strict limit. Upper limit depends about how many arguments IN clause in database can handle. For example with Oracle limit is 1000.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is - practically - whatever fits in JVM Heap memory.
Or, theoretically, whatever the collection can address, which is probably something like 2^32-1 or so 2^64-1 in 64-bit JVM. Just guessing.

If the question is "How to put a limit", then see JPA 2.0's [Criteria API](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/criteria)